# What is “dress” in “helped knights dress”?

Tags: grammar

In below sentence:

> Pages also helped knights dress and carried messages.

What is the grammatical relation of *dress*?

Comment: Could you offer a bit more context?

Comment: It could be written as *Pages also helped knights to dress, and carried messages*, if that makes the meaning more clear.

Comment: More context (as jboneca asked): The sentence is in: Johnston, Ruth A.., All Things Medieval: An Encyclopedia of the Medieval World, p431 - you can find it's preview on "Google Books" easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked about the grammatical relation - 'help' here is a transitive verb. 'knights [to] dress' is a non-finite clause.

See my comment above about the rhetorical device.

Answer (score 4):

> Pages
>   1. helped knights dress
>   - and [pages]
>   2. carried messages.

It is a simple *parallelism* or *zeugma* ([type 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma)): you have two finite verbs, *helped* and *carried*, and the subject, *pages*, is omitted in the second branch of the sentence. So you have one full clause, *pages helped knights dress*, and one elliptical clause, *[pages] carried messages*, connected by the conjunction *and*.

***Update:***

As to the word *dress*, it is an infinitive. The finite verb *help* is used with an **object/accusative and an infinitive**, like *she helped him escape*. Some verbs allow this construction, like *she let him go, they saw her go, she heard them go*, etc.

Note that the verb *help* can also be used with an infinitive but without an object: *she helped paint the room, they helped defeat the boss* (*the room* and *the boss* are the objects of *paint* and *defeat*, not of *helped*).

Comment: I think it's a type two, rather than a type three - the subject is the same. In the type three examples, the subjects are different.

Comment: @LeonConrad: I don't think so: *Type 2 — Zeugma (often also called Syllepsis, or Semantic Syllepsis): where a single word is used with two other parts of a sentence but **must be understood differently in relation to each.** This type of figure is not grammatically incorrect, but creates its effect by **seeming at first hearing to be incorrect, by exploiting multiple shades of meaning in a single word or phrase.***

Comment: on reflection, I don't think it fits either figure. If anything, the best fit is an Ellipsis (omission of 'pages').

Comment: OP asked about the grammar of *dress*.

Comment: @LeonConrad: *Zeugma (Type 3): The Oxford Dictionary of Literary Terms offers a much broader definition for zeugma, describing a zeugma as any case of parallelism and ellipsis working together so that a single word governs two or more other parts of a sentence.* This fits the example.

Comment: @bib: Oh, dear, you are right! How could I have overlooked that last bit? I have extended my answer.

Comment: @Cerberus - Interesting point - rhetorical theorists are notoriously inconsistent in their definition of terms - Howard (2010) defines Zeugma as 'The joining of two or more part of a sentence with a single common verb or adjective. A Zeugma employs both Ellipsis, the omission of words which are easily understood, and Parallelism, the balance of several words or phrases.' Baldick (1991) cites a common verb or preposition with 2 objects, or 2 subjects. Leith (2011) applies it only to verbs, and cites position (pro-, hypo-, meso-) as subsets. He references Diazeugma as applying to common subject.

Comment: @LeonConrad: Yes, and Wikipedia has yet another set of definitions...but the construction in the example is *generally* considered a kind of zeugma in English (although, in Dutch, it is normally defined as Wikipedia's second definition).

Comment: @Cerberus - Agreed - a type of zeugma - see the Silva Rhetoricae list of parallellisms here for the distinction between zeugma and diazeugma: http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/Groupings/of%20Parallelism.htm